# mismatch in filter() using != and ==

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr

Using the dataset below, I am having trouble to remove the rows that have the value "Not a stewardship group" under the field "Research". Based on prior analysis using `table(X$Research)`, I know that the number of rows tha should be gone is 12. If I use the dplyr package to do `filter(X, Research == "Not a stewardship group")`, the output are 12 rows with the filtered value. However, if I run `filter(X, Research != "Not a stewardship group")`, 48 rows are removed, instead of 12.

If I do `X[X$Research != "Not a stewardship group",]`, the number of rows removed is the assumed as correct, 12.

What might be the reason for the `filter()` command to behave like this when using the "!=" logical operator?

data:
`X <- structure(list(Research = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA,  4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L,  NA, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L,  4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  3L, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L,  4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L,  4L, NA, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("N - 10%", "N - 5%",  "Not a stewardship group", "Y"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA,  719L), class = "data.frame")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned [in this thread](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3196), it turns out that the issue was the `filter()` excludes `NA` values by default, so the 36 rows with `NA` were also being excluded. Switching the filter conditions to `filter(X, Research != "Not a stewardship group" | is.na(Research))` did the trick.